# How to redirect with react-router while preserving initial query parameters?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my routes I have

```
<Route>
    <Redirect from="/" to="/view/something"/>
    ...
</Route>
```

But if I hit the root url with `rooturl/?query=somequery` I lose the query paremeter after the redirect. How can I preserve all query parameters after redirect?

Comment: My solutions for: - [react-router v3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057800/746347);
- [react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823112/746347).

Answer (score -2):

I hope it will help: https://github.com/rackt/react-router/issues/1034

Here you can specify and reuse your existing query params after redirect like this:

`<Redirect from="/foo/:id" to="/bar/:id"/>` (`id` will be reused).

Also you might want to have some hooks right before/after transition is actually done for some kind of routing management. It's possible to do with `onEnter` and `onLeave` hooks. You can read about it in official [docs](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md#enter-and-leave-hooks).