# Preserve query parameters in react-router

Tags: reactjs, react-router

In my react application I have a few parameters that the user comes to the application that provide some information about where they came from. Is there a way using react-router to preserve these query params throughout the entire application. meaning every time a route is changed Id like those query params to stay in the url. The only examples I've seen are passing query params between routes but not keeping them around for every route.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Kind of. I intercepted history.listen and added a check to see if the parameters are there or not. If they aren't I added them from redux. It works ok for now but I'd to like make something built into react-router directly.

Comment: is it works for react router v4?

Comment: @Josh see my answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATE**

[Solution for react-router v4](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56823112/746347) is available.

**Solution for react-router v3:**

I wrote this little [history](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history) v3 (it's compatible with [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router) v3) enhancer in Typescript. It will preserve given set of query parameters. Be careful - history passed to this function has to be enhanced with [useQueries](https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/v3/docs/QuerySupport.md).

```
import {History, Location, LocationDescriptor} from 'history'

export default function preserveQueryHistory(history: History, queryParameters: string[]): History {
    function preserveQueryParameters(path: LocationDescriptor): Location {
        const location = history.createLocation(path)
        const currentQuery = history.getCurrentLocation().query
        for (let p of queryParameters) {
            const v = (currentQuery as any)[p]
            if (v) {
                location.query[p] = v
            }
        }
        return location
    }
    return {
        ...history,
        push(path: LocationDescriptor) {
            history.push(preserveQueryParameters(path))
        },
        replace(path: LocationDescriptor) {
            history.replace(preserveQueryParameters(path))
        }
    }
}
```

Now use it to create history:

```
import useQueries from 'history/lib/useQueries'
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import preserveQueryHistory from './preserveQueryHistory'

const history = preserveQueryHistory(useQueries(createBrowserHistory)(), ['language'])
```

And in react-router:

```
<Router history={history}>
...
</Router>
```

**More ultimate solution** with `CreateHistory` enhancer function that embeds applying `useQueries` enhancer and provides ability to inject custom `History` enhancer:

```
import {CreateHistory, History, HistoryOptions, HistoryQueries, Location, LocationDescriptor} from 'history'
import useQueries from 'history/lib/useQueries'

function preserveQueryParameters(history: History, queryParameters: string[], path: LocationDescriptor): Location {
    const location = history.createLocation(path)
    const currentQuery = history.getCurrentLocation().query
    for (let p of queryParameters) {
        const v = (currentQuery as any)[p]
        if (v) {
            location.query[p] = v
        }
    }
    return location
}

function enhanceHistory<H>(history: History & H, queryParameters: string[]): History & H {
    return Object.assign({}, history, {
        push(path: LocationDescriptor) {
            history.push(preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, path))
        },
        replace(path: LocationDescriptor) {
            history.replace(preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, path))
        }
    })
}

export function createPreserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer<O, H, H2>(createHistory: CreateHistory<O, H>,
    queryParameters: string[], enhancer: (h: History) => History & H2): CreateHistory<O, H & H2 & HistoryQueries> {
    return function (options?: HistoryOptions & O): History & H & H2 & HistoryQueries {
        let h = enhancer(useQueries(createHistory)(options)) as History & H & H2 & HistoryQueries
        return enhanceHistory<H & H2 & HistoryQueries>(h, queryParameters)
    }
}

export function createPreserveQueryHistory<O, H>(createHistory: CreateHistory<O, H>,
    queryParameters: string[]): CreateHistory<O, H & HistoryQueries> {
    return createPreserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer<O, H, {}>(createHistory, queryParameters, h => h)
}

export function preserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer<H, H2>(history: History & H, queryParameters: string[],
    enhancer: (h: History) => History & H2): History & HistoryQueries & H & H2 {
    return createPreserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer(
        function () {
            return history
        },
        queryParameters, enhancer)()
}

export function preserveQueryHistory<H>(history: History & H, queryParameters: string[]): History & HistoryQueries & H {
    return preserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer<H, {}>(history, queryParameters, h => h)
}
```

Usage with [syncHistoryWithStore](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router-redux#history--synchistorywithstorehistory-store-options) react-router-redux v4 `History` enhancer:

```
import createBrowserHistory from 'history/lib/createBrowserHistory'
import {createPreserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer} from './preserveQueryHistory'
import {syncHistoryWithStore} from 'react-router-redux'

const store = ...

const history = createPreserveQueryHistoryWithEnhancer(createBrowserHistory, ['language'], function (h: History) {
    return syncHistoryWithStore(h, store)
})()
```

Comment: cool solution. definitely further than I would've ventured to go writing my own history module.

Answer (score -4):

In this case you can use a Store that holds URL state and you can use browserHistory to push custom history state.

https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/Histories.md#browserhistory

```
import { browserHistory } from 'react-router'

browserHistory.push({});
```

[Here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/NavigatingOutsideOfComponents.md) is a link how to navigate outside components