# How can I preserve a single query string value between routes in React Router?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I want to keep `locale=en-US` in the query string even when navigating between routes. I want the rest of my code to be blissfully ignorant of the `locale=en-US` query string value and automatically pass it along when I use a `<Link>`. How can I do this?

Comment: Also see my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/44057800/746347

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I learned that React Router does not provide this functionality out of the box, but one could create a custom `Link` component as suggested by @michal-cumpl like this:

```
import { Link as ReactRouterLink } from 'react-router'
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import merge from 'merge'
import url from 'url'

const QUERY_PARAMS_TO_PRESERVE = ['locale', 'foo', 'bar']

const makeToObj = (to, query) => {
  if (typeof to === 'string') {
    const u = url.parse(to, true)
    to = {
      pathname: u.pathname,
      query: u.query,
      hash: u.hash,
    }
  }

  if (to.query) {
    to.query = merge(query, to.query)
  } else {
    to.query = query
  }

  return to
}

class Link extends Component {
  render() {
    const currentQuery = url.parse(window.location.href, true).query
    const queryToPreserve = {}
    QUERY_PARAMS_TO_PRESERVE.forEach(x => queryToPreserve[x] = currentQuery[x])

    const to = makeToObj(this.props.to, queryToPreserve)

    return (
      <ReactRouterLink to={to}>
        {this.props.children}
      </ReactRouterLink>
    )
  }
}

export { Link }
export default Link
```

Note that this breaks when using third party tools that integrate with React Router, such as react-router-bootstrap's `LinkContainer`.

Answer (score 1):

To achieve this, you can pass the following object to the `Link` `to` prop:

- `pathname`: A string representing the path to link to.
- `query`: An object of key:value pairs to be stringified.
- `hash`: A hash to put in the URL, e.g. #a-hash.

Then you can write a component that will read and parse querystring from `window.location.href` and render `Link`.

https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/docs/API.md#link

Comment: I was worried I would have to write a custom `Link` component. See my own answer below for my solution.

Comment: This approach breaks when you use, for example, react-router-bootstrap's `LinkContainer`. Really need this to be in React Router itself I think.

Comment: What about navigating back/forward?