# How to preserve query parameters in react-router v4

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-v4

Users redirected to my app after login (server on java), and they have url, which looks like this 
http://10.8.0.29:8083/html/?locale=RU&token=1c5c71f2-dcda-4a51-8cf6-f8f6ff1031d0&returnTo=http://10.8.0.23:8080/

(with some params, html - is folder where sources located). I need to preserve this params while navigate on my app. So far I didn't found any simple solution to this problem except this [How to redirect with react-router while preserving initial query parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34956031/how-to-redirect-with-react-router-while-preserving-initial-query-parameters) old question, so I arise this question again, in hope. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to extract those parameters and put them in your store yourself (redux or flex).

Comment: I know how to extract (window.location.search), I can save it in store, but how to put it back while navigate in all routes?

Comment: Just normal dispatch/reducer cycle.

Comment: And what? Please, clarify.

Comment: See my answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/44057800/746347

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works properly with useLocation hook of react-router, try the below

```
import { Link, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
    
function CustomPage() {

      const { search } = useLocation();
    
      return (
        <>
          <p>Preserve the query params?</p>
          <Link to={`/your-next-location${search}`}>Next link</Link>
        </>
      );
 }
```

Or make the route navigation through push method

```
 import { useHistory, useLocation } from 'react-router-dom';
 /*...
   .
   .
 ...*/
 const history = useHistory();
 const { search } = useLocation();
 /*...
   .
   .
 ...*/
 history.push({pathname:`/your-next-location${search}`});
```

Comment: That's a pretty nice and simple solution, thanks

Comment: Although it is useful for you, you are welcome @EricsonWillians

Answer (score 14):

I already shared [my solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44057800/746347) for react-router v3 in the comment to your question.

Below is my solution for react-router v4.

Use the following `createPreserveQueryHistory` function to override `history.push` and `history.replace` methods so they will preserve specified query parameters:

```
import queryString from 'query-string';
import {createBrowserHistory} from 'history'

function preserveQueryParameters(history, preserve, location) {
    const currentQuery = queryString.parse(history.location.search);
    if (currentQuery) {
        const preservedQuery = {};
        for (let p of preserve) {
            const v = currentQuery[p];
            if (v) {
                preservedQuery[p] = v;
            }
        }
        if (location.search) {
            Object.assign(preservedQuery, queryString.parse(location.search));
        }
        location.search = queryString.stringify(preservedQuery);
    }
    return location;
}

function createLocationDescriptorObject(location, state) {
    return typeof location === 'string' ? { pathname: location, state } : location;
}

function createPreserveQueryHistory(createHistory, queryParameters) {
    return (options) => {
        const history = createHistory(options);
        const oldPush = history.push, oldReplace = history.replace;
        history.push = (path, state) => oldPush.apply(history, [preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, createLocationDescriptorObject(path, state))]);
        history.replace = (path, state) => oldReplace.apply(history, [preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, createLocationDescriptorObject(path, state))]);
        return history;
    };
}

const history = createPreserveQueryHistory(createBrowserHistory, ['locale', 'token', 'returnTo'])();
```

Then use it in your router definition:

```
<Router history={history}>
    ...
</Router>
```

**For those who use TypeScript**:

```
import {History, LocationDescriptor, LocationDescriptorObject} from 'history'
import queryString from 'query-string'
import LocationState = History.LocationState

type CreateHistory<O, H> = (options?: O) => History & H

function preserveQueryParameters(history: History, preserve: string[], location: LocationDescriptorObject): LocationDescriptorObject {
    const currentQuery = queryString.parse(history.location.search)
    if (currentQuery) {
        const preservedQuery: { [key: string]: unknown } = {}
        for (let p of preserve) {
            const v = currentQuery[p]
            if (v) {
                preservedQuery[p] = v
            }
        }
        if (location.search) {
            Object.assign(preservedQuery, queryString.parse(location.search))
        }
        location.search = queryString.stringify(preservedQuery)
    }
    return location
}

function createLocationDescriptorObject(location: LocationDescriptor, state?: LocationState): LocationDescriptorObject {
    return typeof location === 'string' ? {pathname: location, state} : location
}

export function createPreserveQueryHistory<O, H>(createHistory: CreateHistory<O, H>,
                                                 queryParameters: string[]): CreateHistory<O, H> {
    return (options?: O) => {
        const history = createHistory(options)
        const oldPush = history.push, oldReplace = history.replace
        history.push = (path: LocationDescriptor, state?: LocationState) =>
            oldPush.apply(history, [preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, createLocationDescriptorObject(path, state))])
        history.replace = (path: LocationDescriptor, state?: LocationState) =>
            oldReplace.apply(history, [preserveQueryParameters(history, queryParameters, createLocationDescriptorObject(path, state))])
        return history
    }
}
```

Comment: `createLocationDescriptorObject` did not work for me. I needed to replace `{pathname: location, state}` part with `{ ...parsePath(location), state }`, where `parsePath` is imported from history.

Comment: @GennadyDogaev, re ur comment above, what was not working? i used `{pathname: location, state}` it seems to work, but with limited testing. what i might missed?

Comment: missing search and hash?

Comment: @innek this was long ago, so I can't remember exact reason why it didn't work

Comment: In `react-router-dom` v6, the `Router` component should be replaced with `unstable_HistoryRouter`.

Answer (score 13):

In React-Router 4.3 (not sure about earlier versions), if you have a `<Route>` just above, something like this should work: (this is in Typescript)

```
Route({ path: ..., render: (props) => function() {
  Redirect({ ...,
      to: { pathname: ... search: props.location.search, ... }})
});
```

Explanation: You use the `render: (props) => ....` proprety of the `<Route>` tag, instead of `component: ...`, because `render` gives you `props`, so then inside the `<Redirect>` you can use `props.location.search` and in that way access the current query params, and reuse in the redirect.

If there's no `<Route>` above, maybe you cannot. I just asked here: [How preserve query string and hash fragment, in React-Router 4 <Switch><Redirect>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869083/how-preserve-query-string-and-hash-fragment-in-react-router-4-switchredirect)

Comment: this redirect approach doesnt seem to work for the following scenario. say, user landed on mysite.com/home?devmode=true, and there is a menu item on site navbar that has link to go to 'mysite.com/projects'. I wanted to preverse the query param `devmode=true`, when i click on 'mysite.com/projects'. redirect like this would cause infinite loop `      <Redirect from='mysite.com/projects' to='mysite.com/projects?devmode=true'
      />`

Comment: @innek Is that something you think might happen or that actually happened?  I think `to: ...` is for *paths* only? (Don't totally remember.) What if you construct the `Route({ ... Redirect({...` list dynamically, and exclude  the redirect, if you're at `mysite.com/projects?devmode=true` already?

Answer (score 1):

I switched off the hash router in this project, which preserves all parameters in route.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: Mohammed, read docs https://v5.reactrouter.com/web/api/HashRouter

Answer (score 1):

One option if you need a link to an **#anchor** is to use this library  https://github.com/rafrex/react-router-hash-link and do something like this:

```
import { NavHashLink } from 'react-router-hash-link';

...
<NavHashLink elementId='targetID' to='' smooth >     
    my text
</NavHashLink>
...
```

This works in React-Router v5 too.