# How to replace current push state using react-router-dom?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am using [react-router-dom](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-router-dom) `props.history.replace` to replace query string in URL (works as expected).

When I navigate to another URL using `Link` component and hit back, URL doesn't reflect previous push state (set using `props.history.replace`).

For example: we're at `/privacy-guides` and search for keyword `veracrypt`.

Following logic is executed:

```js
props.history.replace({
  pathname: "/privacy-guides",
  search: queryString.stringify({
    search: value,
  }),
})
```

We're now at `/privacy-guides?search=veracrypt`.

We click on `<Link to="/privacy-guides/how-to-backup-and-encrypt-data-using-rsync-and-veracrypt-on-macos">`.

We're now at `/privacy-guides/how-to-backup-and-encrypt-data-using-rsync-and-veracrypt-on-macos` and click back button.

We're now at `/privacy-guides` vs expected `/privacy-guides?search=veracrypt`.

Why?

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43613140/how-to-preserve-query-parameters-in-react-router-v4

Comment: why not ```props.history.push(`/privacy-guides?search=${value}`)```

Comment: @Pengin I also tried that... and it doesn't work either... plus I like the idea of replacing current state vs adding state each times search changes (on keystrokes pause keystrokes for example).